# Condition for detecting cycle in graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

I am applying DFS on a graph and maintaining state (discovered/Not discovered , Processed/Not Processed)  of each node. When I put a new node in DFS stack its state is discovered but not processed. And When a node is removed from Dfs stack its state is discovered and processed. 
Let's say I am visiting a new node Y from X in DFS and this is my condition for detecting cycle.

```
if(discovered(y) && !processed(y))
```

Is this condition correct for directed graphs?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I belive it is. My reasoning would be to examine possible states of the node like this:

- y is not discovered (and not processed) - we were never here -> not a cycle
- y is discovered but not processed - we are in the process of processing this node, therefore, we are in its descendant -> we found a cycle
- y is discovered but processed - we already processed y and all paths originated from it, so we can't be in its descendat -> not a cycle

Comment: Yes, seems reasonable to me. But When I was looking for algorithms for the same, they were complicated and were using different approaches so I got confused.